# PHP mail don't send anything

Tags: php, email

I ran this PHP script in a dedicated server (OVH Kimsufi, Debian 6.0 stable).

```
<?php
$msg = "coucou les amis";
$sub = "test";
$head  = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";
echo mail("31415@yopmail.com", $msg, $msg, $head);
?>
```

Mail returned 1 but the email was never received... How to fix it ?

Comment: Is `example.com` actually running on (= resolving to) the server you send the E-Mail from?

Comment: This would look like junk mail to any filter, only use valid from email and should match at least one email you have setup for the account, else your server may not send it from its spool. also note the `$msg` is also used as the subject in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the exim ( = sendmail) default config. It do not allow direct SMTP sending (only local).

```
# dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

Answer (score 2):

> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.

PHP has sent the message. Whether it reached its destination or not is beyond PHP's control.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon your server whether your server allow you to send mail using php or not

Comment: I think it'allow, how to check it ?

Comment: @torgal contact your server center

Comment: I did it, I wait for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot that can wrong. Are you using [Sendmail](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/) for example. Maybe you should inspect those logs, which probably are located at.

```
cat /var/log/mail.log
```

Or maybe your email does get send, but gets delivered in the spam folder?

I would instead advice you to outsource sending out emails using for example [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com). Sendgrid is free when you sent less than 200 emails daily.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake and used `$msg` in place of `$sub` where subject was required as argument to the `mail()` function.

```
$msg = "coucou les amis";
$sub = "test";
$head  = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";
echo mail("31415@yopmail.com", $sub, $msg, $head);
```

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the problem described in holodoc's post, you shall consider getting rid of `mail()`, which is unreliable.